# Image Matching for homogeneous surfaces

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, sift, surf

I have built an image-matching code via OpenCV and the feature detection method that I am using currently is SIFT. The main problem that I am experiencing is that if the image has a homogenous surface, the matches will either fail or give a false positive.

Is there another way that I can match images that are homogeneous in nature (i.e. little or no features identified)

Comment: Can you add those images as examples?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the late response. I am new to this forum and did not see your comment. So i am referring to something such as a ceramic tile for example. If I take two images of the same ceramic tile, the algorithm fails to find enough feature points to match the images. I was wondering if there is a way that I can increase those feature points